# How can I calibrate a camera with a fixed focus set up for long focal range?

Tags: matlab, camera, calibration

I have a PointGrey BlackFly with a manually-adjusted lens set suspended 5m high, viewing targets up to 12m away laterally - approximately 13m distance to target.

Can you suggest a good method to calibrate this camera?

I have MatLab available, but the calibration toolbox wants to use checkerboard pattern and I do not think that I can produce one large enough to calibrate with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use to calibrate camera with Agisoft Lens software. It is free.
http://download.cnet.com/windows/agisoft/3260-20_4-10180989-1.html 
And you don't need to print anything, it uses full view of Desktop monitor for chess board. Get your images and import it in software. After all you can get camera parameters.

cheers.

Agisoft lens demo video
https://youtu.be/jxUNwOaz_TU